# Encrypt a timestamp in PHP and decrypt in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, encoding, integer

I need to encrypt a unix timestamp to make a call to a third party API. In their documentation they specify I must use:

- Algorithm: 128-bit AES, Mode: CBC
- Padding: PKCS5Padding
- Initialization Vector: "0000000000000000"

And then they give an example:

> Clients must test their implementation using the timestamp 1464284796, the initialization vector: '0000000000000000' and the secret key b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80 which resulting in the base64 auth_token 6BH3hg1cqQJOK6sG8gw7Xw==

They even give sample code to generate the encrypted timestamp, problem is that they're using Java and we're using PHP. Everything I try in PHP does not match the expected output, which is 6BH3hg1cqQJOK6sG8gw7Xw== .

Here's their Java sample:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;
class Encryptor {
    private String initialVector;
    private static final String TRANFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    String encrypt(SecretKeySpec key, long timestamp) throws Exception {
        byte[] encryptedBytes =
            getEncryptingCipher(key).doFinal(Longs.toByteArray(timestamp));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }
    private Cipher getEncryptingCipher(SecretKeySpec key) throws
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
    InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Cipher encryptingCipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANFORMATION);
        encryptingCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(initialVector.getBytes()));
        return encryptingCipher;
    }
    private SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String key) throws DecoderException {
        byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALGORITHM);
    }
    void setInitialVector(String initialVector) {
        this.initialVector = initialVector;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor();
encryptor.setInitialVector("0000000000000000");
//Expensive operation so only performed once, re-use the key spec instance
SecretKeySpec keySpec =
encryptor.getSecretKeySpec("b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80");
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
String authToken = encryptor.encrypt(keySpec, timestamp);
```

My attempts in PHP:

```
[acool@acool ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo openssl_encrypt( '1464284796','AES-128-CBC','b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80',null,'0000000000000000');
8PM7LQM7Xmb2NCBE3Hp00g==
php >
```

And then:

```
<?php

function encrypt($message, $initialVector, $secretKey) {
    return base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $secretKey,
            $message,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $initialVector
        )
    );
}

function encrypt_something($input)
{
    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael-128', 'cbc');
    $input = pkcs5_pad($input, $size);

    $key = 'b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80';
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, '0000000000000000');
    $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
    if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}

echo encrypt_something('1464284796');

//echo encrypt('1464284796','0000000000000000','b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80');



[acool@acool ~]$ php -f api.php 
UXRvTOIPiiYfBUoDFRaC5w==
```

Honestly, I don't have much idea of what I'm doing, specifically in JAVA. I don't even know how to run the sample code.

**UPDATE**

Third party reached out to us with a revision of their sample:

> Note: clients must test their implementation using the timestamp
>   1464284796, the initialization vector: '0000000000000000' and the
>   secret key b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80 which resulting in the
>   base64 auth_token ZnNmKbcdxRrYTDBgQKI9aQ==

The solution is to revome `pack` function:

```
$ts  = '1464284796';
$key = "b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80";
$authToken = openssl_encrypt( $ts, 'AES-128-CBC', hextobin($key), null, '0000000000000000');

function hextobin($hexstr) 
{
    $n    = strlen($hexstr); 
    $sbin ="";
    $i    =0; 
    while($i<$n)
    {
        $a =substr($hexstr,$i,2);
        $c = pack("H*",$a); 
        if ($i==0){$sbin=$c;} 
        else {$sbin.=$c;} 
        $i+=2; 
    }
    return $sbin;
}
```

Comment: Could a system call to run ready java code be an alternative? This could get answers and might be easier than implementing all that stuff in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are not simply decimal strings. You have to encode them to a binary representation. This can be done with [`pack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php). Since `Longs.toByteArray(timestamp)` encodes the timestamp in 64-bit big-endian notation, you have to match this encoding:

```
$ts = "\0\0\0\0" . pack('N', '1464284796');
echo openssl_encrypt( $ts, 'AES-128-CBC', hex2bin('b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80'), 
        null, '0000000000000000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Java APIs you're using. Do they really expect hex strings? That's very uncommon in Java.

Your code here says "initialVector.getBytes()", which suggests that the API wants a byte array, not a broken byte array representation of a hex string :)

The reason that PHP or JS code often uses hex strings is that there's not support for byte arrays in these languages (at least traditionally, there actually are byte arrays in modern JS).